# Задание по программированию: Складирование ноутбуков на Python

Tags: python

Я не могу обнаружить ошибку в коде. Помогите найти ошибку (код ниже, после задания):

> На склад, который имеет форму прямоугольного параллелепипеда, привезли ноутбуки, упакованные в коробки. Каждая коробка также имеет
> форму прямоугольного параллелепипеда. По правилам хранения коробки с
> ноутбуками должны быть размещены на складе с выполнением следующих
> двух условий:
>
> - Стороны коробок должны быть параллельны сторонам склада.
> - Коробку при помещении на склад разрешается расположить где угодно (с
>   выполнением предыдущего условия), в том числе на другой коробке, но все
>   коробки должны быть ориентированы одинаково (т.е. нельзя одну коробку
>   расположить “стоя”, а другую —“лежа”)
>
> Напишите программу, которая по размерам склада и размерам коробки с ноутбуком > определит максимальное количество ноутбуков, которое может быть размещено на
> складе.
>
> **Формат ввода**
>
> Программа получает на вход шесть натуральных чисел. Первые три задают
> длину, высоту и ширину склада. Следующие три задают соответственно
> длину, высоту и ширину коробки с ноутбуком.
>
> **Формат вывода**
>
> Программа должна вывести одно число — максимальное количество
> ноутбуков, которое может быть размещено на складе.
>
> Примеры
>
> ```
> Тест 1
> Входные данные: 100 200 300 1 2 3
> Вывод программы: 1000000
>
> Тест 2
> Входные данные: 100 200 300 3 2 1
> Вывод программы: 1000000
>
> Тест 3
> Входные данные: 100 100 1 2 2 2
> Вывод программы: 
>
> Тест 4 Входные данные: 7 7 7 3 3 3
> Вывод программы: 8
> ```

```
a = int(input())
# while a != -1:
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
m1 = int(a // x) * int(b // y) * int(c // z)
m2 = int(a // x) * int(b // z) * int(c // y)
m3 = int(a // y) * int(b // a) * int(c // z)
m4 = int(a // y) * int(b // z) * int(c // x)
m5 = int(a // z) * int(b // a) * int(c // y)
m6 = int(a // z) * int(b // y) * int(c // x)
if a >= x and b >= y and c >= z:
    if m1 > m2 and m1 > m3 and m1 > m4 and m1 > m5 and m1 > m6:
        print(m1)
    elif m2 > m3 and m2 > m4 and m2 > m5 and m2 > m6:
        print(m2)
    elif m3 > m4 and m3 > m5 and m3 > m6:
        print(m3)
    elif m4 > m5 and m4 > m6:
        print(m4)
    elif m5 > m6:
        print(m5)
    else:
        print(m6)
else:
    print(0)
# a = int(input())
```

Comment: if a >= x and b >= y and c >= z неправильно, могут быть другие методы упаковки, a к y, и т.п. Значения m1-m6 я б просто занёс в массив и использовал бы стандартную сортировку Питона и всё, должно быть правильно

Answer (score 1):

Привет! Мое решение, только на if.

```
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
c1 = int(input())
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())

d1 = (a1 // x) * (b1 // y) * (c1 // z)
d2 = (a1 // x) * (c1 // y) * (b1 // z)
d3 = (b1 // x) * (c1 // y) * (a1 // z)
d4 = (b1 // x) * (a1 // y) * (c1 // z)
d5 = (c1 // x) * (a1 // y) * (b1 // z)
d6 = (c1 // x) * (b1 // y) * (a1 // z)

if d1 >= d2:
    d2 = d1
if d3 >= d4:
    d4 = d2
if d5 >= d6:
    d6 = d5

if d2 >= d4 and d2 >= d6:
    print(d2)
elif d4 >= d6:
    print(d4)
else:
    print(d6)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Первая проблема:**
В 2 строках (`m3 = ...` и `m5 = ...`) вместо `b // a` нужно быть `b // x`:

```
m3 = int(a // y) * int(b // x) * int(c // z)

m5 = int(a // z) * int(b // x) * int(c // y)
```

---

**Вторая проблема:**
Ваша программа ожидает на вводе *6 чисел в одной строке*, а не 6 чисел в 6 строках.

Вы можете это сделать так:

```
inp = input()                      # ввод строки из 6 чисел
lst = inp.split()                  # split() сделает список из 6 элементов
a, b, c, x, y, z = map(int, lst)   # map применит функцию int на каждый элемент списка lst
```

или - так как третья строка слишком сложная, вместо ней постепенно

```
а = int(lst[0])
b = int(lst[1])
c = int(lst[2])
x = int(lst[3])
y = int(lst[4])
z = int(lst[5])
```

---

**Примечание:**

Вместо сложной многострочной команды `if` возможно использовать функцию `max()`, и вся баша программа сократится на

```
inp = input()                      # ввод строки из 6 чисел
lst = inp.split()                  # split() сделает список из 6 элементов
a, b, c, x, y, z = map(int, lst)   # map применит функцию int на каждый элемент списка lst

m1 = int(a // x) * int(b // y) * int(c // z)
m2 = int(a // x) * int(b // z) * int(c // y)
m3 = int(a // y) * int(b // a) * int(c // z)
m4 = int(a // y) * int(b // z) * int(c // x)
m5 = int(a // z) * int(b // a) * int(c // y)
m6 = int(a // z) * int(b // y) * int(c // x)

print(max(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6))
```

Answer (score 0):

вот еще вариант, для случаев когда max() запрещено использовать:

```
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
d, e, f = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
result = 0
check = 0
check = (a // d) * (b // e) * (c // f)
if check > result:
    result = check
check = (a // d) * (b // f) * (c // e)
    if check > result:
    result = check
check = (a // e) * (b // d) * (c // f)
    if check > result:
    result = check
check = (a // e) * (b // f) * (c // d)
    if check > result:
    result = check
check = (a // f) * (b // d) * (c // e)
    if check > result:
    result = check
check = (a // f) * (b // e) * (c // d)
    if check > result:
    result = check
print(result)
```

поскольку в этой задаче не нужно упорядочивать все шесть чисел, а нужно только выбрать максимальное.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1, b1, c1 = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
a2, b2, c2 = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

warehouse = [a1, b1, c1]
warehouse.sort()
box = [a2, b2, c2]
box.sort()

i = 0
temp = 0
while i < len(warehouse):
    temp = warehouse[i] % box[i]
    warehouse[i] = warehouse[i] - temp
    i += 1

useful_warehouse_volume = warehouse[0] * warehouse[1] * warehouse[2]
box_volume = box[0] * box[1] * box[2]

print(useful_warehouse_volume // box_volume)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).